# SPAM bots using gmail address with punctuation (dots) wordpress

Tags: wordpress, spam-prevention

I am using wpforms for my website. And I am trying to block out fake gmail adresses. Bots (or people) sending spam messages using gmail adress containing dots (punctuation), plus signs. etc.

Example:
vmaa.k.o.v.a.89.0.
sanja.fila.t.o.vy.g.99s

Any ideas how to tackle these adresses without blocking all gmail.com adresses ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was truly simple.
In the email Denylist (of WpForms) just add this filter: *.*@gmail.com